# How does Kafka connect assign tasks to workers in the distributed mode?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Does kafka connector have a central process that handles tasks distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. The `group.id` of the Connect cluster joins a cluster, in which there is a Group coordinator that manages communication between each.